# Strategy Pattern and inheriting boilerplate functionality

Tags: inheritance, composition, strategy-pattern

I've read that when using the Strategy Pattern, you should stick to composition rather than inheritance. But does this mean that any inheritance at all is bad practice? If there is functionality to be shared between similar strategies is it anachronistic to implement a base class to encapsulate that functionality? Below is an example that could be better, but I hope illustrates my question.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AdditionStrategyInterface(ABC):    
    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, num1,  num2):
        raise NotImplementedError


class AdditionStrategy(AdditionStrategyInterface):
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2


class AdditionPlusFourStrategyBase(AdditionStrategyInterface, ABC):
    def add_four(self, num):
        return num + 4

    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        raise NotImplementedError


class AdditionPlusFourStrategy(AdditionPlusFourStrategyBase):
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        return self.add_four(num1 + num2)


class AdditionPlusEightStrategy(AdditionPlusFourStrategyBase):
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        return self.add_four(self.add_four(num1 + num2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no golden rule for that - and hardly a rule of thumb to answer this question accurate. As always it fully depends on what problem you intend to solve and how long lasting your solution is going to be.

The motive behind *inheritance* is to *share common behaviour between common types of objects*. If you have things where you have small differences in the overal behaviour, there is no reason not to use *inheritance*. That was the reason inheritance was invented.

But inheritance comes with a cost:

As mentioned, it does make sense if you have a set of objects, which are *essentially* the same; but if you build complex inheritance chains, there is the possibility that you inherit behaviour, which is down the chain not wanted. Or more often you end up debugging the inheritance chain, because you did not understand why behaviour is as it is: in an unexpected way.

That makes inheritance for some scenarios not so favourable.

On the other hand *strategy* is always interesting when you have objects which are not *essentially* the same, but share some common kind of behaviour.

If you will, inheritance models `nouns` and strategy `verbs`.

When looking at languages like Java, you implement strategies with `interfaces` explaining, what "kind" of behaviour is expected: what the *contract* is.
There is no such thing in python though.

»But how does *composition* fit into the picture?« you may ask.

In order to swap behaviour easily out and adhere to the [open closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), you compose behaviour. Your class is open to receive new kinds of behaviour, but is itself closed.

If you implement the strategy pattern, you have no hierarchies and no problem of unwanted behaviour, because you pull in what you need and aren't pushed with behaviour.

That said, there may be cases, where you have a bunch of objects which are *essentially* the same but have aspects, which are better modeled as strategies. There a mixture of both would make a great fit.

The hard thing about programming is, that there are very few *dos* and *dont's* but most of the time you have things, which are kind of good in some context.

Answer (score 2):

The popular advice is not "stick to composition" it's "prefer composition over inheritance". This isn't something you can follow without thinking about it. You really need to understand why you're doing it before you do it.

Inheritance has advantages but comes with many problems. The big advantage is that it doesn't require delegation to work like composition does. That means less boilerplate code. That means less typing at the keyboard.

But it also means you're at risk of the [yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem). Inheritance tends to beget inheritance so soon you have a long chain that forces readers of the code to bounce up and down trying to follow program behavior.

Also, inheritance sneaks in the backdoor. It lets programmers assume they have intimate knowledge of the parent they are inheriting from. That encourages coupling beyond what delegation would since it would stick to using the normal interface.

Composition used with delegation provides polymorphism like inheritance does but encourages code that is more flexible. That's why it is sometimes prefered.

Now it's not that I refuse to ever use inheritance. One of my favorite uses is to give exceptions new names:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may be wrong, but potentially couldn't you end up with a similar chain of classes by going too deep into composition? A strategy class that uses a strategy class that uses two strategy classes, etc...? The answer to that question is most likely that the code isn't organized well, but that could also be the answer to the yo-yo problem.

Comment: @AllieFitter yes you can. But since you're maintaining a public style relationship through the normal API it's no more confusing than using a library. No surprise declarations. No needing to dig past an abstraction to understand what is going on because the abstraction is doing what it's supposed to do: hide the details.

Comment: Call me wrong, but how does inheritance mess with the internals if derived classes don't have access to private methods and members?

Answer (score 1):

The [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) is in fact an application of composition over inheritance:  `context` uses composition:

- this allows to dynamically change the strategy it refers to.
- this allows also to use several unrelated strategies, and handle them separately, thus enforcing [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/)

The principle of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a general recommendation, because it's tempting to reuse code of class X in class Y by using inheritance, which can be a very bad idea if an Y is not really an X.

The particular risk when over-using inheritance in the case of the strategy pattern, is to combine with inheritance different strategies that should in reality remain independent.  This makes the code more rigid and evolution of code more difficult (combinatorial explosion of classes, redundant code, etc...).

Composition over inheritance is nevertheless a recommendation, and not a divine command.  So if you see that one algorithm encapsulated in a strategy needs a slight variation, you should ask yourself if it is not in reality the symptom that it should belong to an independent strategy.  But if after careful analysis you conclude that it's not, and that inheritance would really be justified, then you shall use it.

---

Silly illustrative example :

```
interface FamilyAStrategy { ... }; 
class A1Strategy implements FamilyAStrategy { ... }; 
class A2Strategy implements FamilyAStrategy { ... }; 

interface FamilyBStrategy { ... }; 
class B1Strategy implements FamilyBStrategy { ... }; 
class B2Strategy implements FamilyBStrategy { ... }; 

// context can combine several families strategies:  
class EventProcessor {
     AStrategy as; 
     BStrategy bs;        
     ...
};
```

If you would be tempted to use inheritance :

```
interface SStrategy { ... }; 
class A1SStrategy implements SStrategy { ... }; 
class A1B1Strategy extends A1SStrategy { ... }; 
class A1B2SStrategy extends A1SStrategy { ... }; 
... // the rest is too awful that I expose it to your sight ;-)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I'm  hearing here and elsewhere this "prefer composition over inheritance" principle is in practice more "use inheritance responsibly. Dont created deeply coupled, Byzantine hierarchies and don't force relationships that don't exist. Decouple code whenever possible and put thought into relationships created by inheritance. "

Comment: @AllieFitter Exactly. Why COI ? How many examples have you seen, where a `Student` inherits from a `Person`, whereas, everyone knows that a `Person` can be a `Student` one Day, and an `Employee` the next day (or event both at the same time).  While COI is general, with the strategy pattern use of inheritance can really hide a need to decouple and create a second family of strategies.  Unfortunately one tend to realize the problem when the "bizantine" hierarchy is there, and then it's painful to refactor.  So the emphasis on COI with strategy is well founded.